# How is the Java classpath set on a Mac?

Tags: java, tomcat

How is the Java classpath set on a Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged the question with [tomcat](/questions/tagged/tomcat), I'll assume that you're running a Java Servlet webapp.

In that case, the classpath covers the JAR files in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the webapp and all class files in `/WEB-INF/classes` folder of the webapp. So you've to drop the 3rd party JAR files and/or your classes exactly there to get them to be visible in the runtime classpath of the webapp.

The `%CLASSPATH%` environment variable is by the way **ignored** by everything else than the `java` executabele which is executed *without* `-jar`, `-cp` and `-classpath` arguments. Don't use it for webapps.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X, I stopped using the `CLASSPATH` environment variable some time ago; I now set it for each project. Too often, I would forget about older, conflicting JARs hiding in the forgotten recesses of an ever growing list of paths. In particular, I don't know of a reason to set it for Tomcat. If you're curious, `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/setclasspath.sh` may be informative.

If you need it for some other reason, the bash incantation to include *this* or *that* is shown below:

```
export CLASSPATH=.:/opt/this/this.jar:/opt/that/that.jar:…
```